# how to use if exists in sql postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists

Can I use IF exists in Postgres?

Something like this

```
if exits(select* from a)
then (select * from b)
else 
(select * from c)
```

I am getting errors. What is the correct way to use it?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** `IF` in pure SQL, but you could combine the two parts of your query with an `UNION ALL` :

---

```
select ...
from b
where EXISTS ( select *
        from a
        where...
        )
UNION ALL
select ...
from c
where NOT EXISTS ( select *
        from a
        where...
        )
     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, but not in this style (looks like MS style). `IF` is available in procedural language [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html). Just in SQL language it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a LEFT JOIN between your tables.

```
SELECT * FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON ....
LEFT JOIN C ON ....
```

That way, if it exists in B then you'll get the answer on the same row.
And if it does not exist in B but in C, you'll get the data from C in the same row too.